# Facebook share not working in mobile browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using below API for Facebook share, It's working in web browser but not in mobile browser.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphoto.php%3Ffbid%3D503650586358491%26set%3Da.447778305279053.102678.420576761332541%26type%3D1&t=Breaking%3A+BUCKWILD%27s+Shain+has+died.+Our+hearts+go+out+to+his+family.+More+info+here%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fon.mtv.com%2F128hbz2

I'm using android phone.

Error message : "Your link could not be found."

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need url for mobile to start http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
Also the rest url wont work like that, you need url site whit the Facebook Open Graph META Tags.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see, the solution offered by vj_andrei doesn't work - the m.facebook.com/sharer url just doesn't exist.
Facebook, however, have re-introduced the [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/), and it works for mobile as well.